# Positive series for use the Ratio test or the Root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question:

for use the Ratio test or the Root test I need the series will be positive or non negative (zero can belong to series? why?)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your question seems to be asking two things: 1) Is it true that to use the ratio test or root test the series must be non-negative? and 2) Can $0$ be in the series? Am I correct?

Comment: Its same.. non-negative say that can 0 be in the series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The root and ratio test are defined in absolute values, so you dont need that the series will be non-negative to use them. But the ratio test requires that the series will be [eventually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventually_(mathematics)) non-zero.

Take a look, by example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test).

Comment: Can i use these tests for series that for example: $a_0 = 0$ ?

Comment: of course. Why you think you cant use them in this case?

Comment: Because that for example, in the ratio test i divide in $a_n$, and what will be if it's $0$?

Comment: @Master the ratio test its a limit, then it is enough that exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n\neq0$ for all $n\ge N$. This is the meaning of "eventually non-zero".

Comment: Thank you about your complete answer!!